# I am trying to create a simple function in javascript to add two numbers but the result isn't getting displayed,

Tags: javascript, html

code:

```js
function add() {
  var first = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('n4').value;
  return first + second;
}
document.getElementById('n5').innerHTML = add();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result"/><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="n3"/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="add();">+</button><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="n4"/>
<p id="n5"></p>
```

Comment: The line where you set the value of `n5` is not in the `add()` function so when do you think that code is executed?

Comment: Can you please edit the code and share it with me? Thanks.  @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 2):

Add the assignment to `n5` into the add function.

Also, don't forget to cast your input into Number.

```js
function add() {
  var first = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('n4').value;
  document.getElementById('n5').innerHTML = (Number(first) + Number(second));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n3"/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="add();">+</button><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="n4"/>
<p id="n5"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to add the value inside the function. Your values are strings and using `+` will concatenate them. For example 4 + 5 will then become 45.

Convert your value using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert it to an int and add the radix, or use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```
function add() {
    var first = document.getElementById('n3').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('n4').value;
    document.getElementById('n5').innerHTML = parseInt(first, 10) + parseInt(second, 10);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look these code you could find your mistake:

```js
function add() {
  var first = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('n4').value;
  var sum=parseInt(first) +  parseInt(second);
  $('#result').val(sum); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="n3"/><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="n4"/>
<button onclick="add();">+</button><br/><br/>
<input  id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the innerHTML setting of `n5` inside the `add()` and convert it number with preceeding `+`. Also I just remove the unused `<input type="text" id="result"/><br/><br/>` line of code.

```js
function add() {
  var first = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('n4').value;
  document.getElementById('n5').innerHTML= +first + +second;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n3"/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="add();">+</button><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="n4"/>
<p id="n5"></p>
```